# Dynamically Show Children of React Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown that loads in a specific ul when a corresponding button is clicked. It seems like there are many correct and incorrect ways of achieving this. Currently I have two different ul's: AddMenu, and RefsMenu. When I click on a link in AddMenu, it will completely remove that ul and replace it with RefsMenu. I only want one child component to load at a time, effectively replacing the body each time a new view is selected.

So far I have:

```
<Dropdown open={ false } currentView={ this.state.currentView } onClick={ this.handleView }>
    <AddMenu title="Add Menu" selected={ false }/>
    <AddRefs title="Add Refs" selected={ false } />
</Dropdown>
```

So what I'm confused about is... How do I select which body element to show/render?
I suppose I could have a handler that says:

```
handleView: function(component, e) {
    this.state.currentView = e.target.value;
}

handleSelected: function() {
    selected += true;
}
```

I've thought about using this.props.children, but I don't think that returns instances so I'm not really sure where to start. Am I way off?

Answer (score 0):

If the DropDown component has knowledge of the current view to show, (which it appears to because your code reference `currentView={this.state.currentView}`), then in your render method you can use that information to conditionally render the children.

As an example,

```
render: function() {
    return (<div>
        {this._getCurrentViewItem()}
    </div>);
},
_getCurrentViewItem: function() {
    var foundChild;
    React.Children.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.props.view === this.props.currentView) {
            foundChild = child;
        }
    });
    return foundChild;
}
```

To make this work you would just need to specify which view each child component is applicable to.

```
<Dropdown open={ false } currentView={ this.state.currentView } onClick={this.handleView }>
    <AddMenu title="Add Menu" view="refsView"/>
    <AddRefs title="Add Refs" view="menuView" />
</Dropdown>
```